# Google API error: over query limit. rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-geocoder, rails-geocoder

The issue is I keep hitting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error when trying to geocode gem locations on a Google Map . I understand that there is a limit to the rate at which you can call the geocoder (as well as the daily limit on total volume), so I need to introduce a pause in between each result in the array.

How do I pause/delay in Rails Controller method to slow it down?

> `geo_localization = "#{latitude},#{longitude}"
>      query = Geocoder.search(geo_localization).first
>      place = query.address`

Answer (score 0):

In the method definition add sleep and that should do the trick for you

```
def geolocation
  begin
    ...
  rescue Geocoder::OverQueryLimitError
    sleep 2
    retry
  end
end
```

Also, there is an alternative, to this, you have an option `timeout` that comes with **geocode**. You need to create a file **config/initializers/geocoder.rb** and set the following. This option, I have not tested though.

```
Geocoder.configure(
  timeout: 10
)
```

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits#problems) as well, it could be any of those cases for you and the only thing you can do now is wait.

Comment: can we increase size geocoder API. Google API error: over query limit

Comment: i will try this but this issue  "Google API error: over query limit"  still comming

Comment: What _size_ are you talking about ?

Comment: What you need to do is, delay when you get **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** error and then perform retry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180888/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-santosh-kumbhar).

Answer (score 0):

Use [sleep](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep) inside method like so:

```
sleep 2
```

That'll sleep for 2 seconds.

Be careful to give an argument. If you just run sleep, the process will sleep forever. (This is useful when you want a thread to sleep until it's woken.)